# Why is rails associating 2 projects per user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When a user's submission is accepted, the project that the submission belongs to should be added to the user through the def finish function. However, when I run User.first.projects on my console, it shows all the projects the user has completed but twice.

For example, if a user's submission for project 1 is accepted, User.first.projects shows project 1 twice,

Submission controller:

```
def accept
  @submission = Submission.find(params[:id])
  @submission.update_attribute(:accepted, true)
  @submission.user.finish(@submission.project)
  redirect_to current_instructor
end
```

Project Model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

User Model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

def finish(project)
  projects << project
end

def finished?(project)
  projects.include?(project)
end
```

Projectsubmissions/show.html.erb:

```
<% if instructor_signed_in? && @submission.accepted != true%>
  <%= link_to("Accept", project_accept_path(@submission.project.course, @submission.project, @submission), :method => :post %>
  <%= link_to("Reject", project_reject_path(@submission.project.course, @submission.project, @submission), :method => :post %>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
match 'courses/:course_id/projects/:project_id/submissions/:id/accept', :to => 'submissions#accept', :as => 'project_accept', :via => :post
match 'courses/:course_id/projects/:project_id/submissions/:id/reject', :to => 'submissions#reject', :as => 'project_reject', :via => :post
```

Submission model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project
```

Console Logs:

```
irb(main):001:0> User.first.projects
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN     "projects_users" ON "projects"."id" = "projects_users"."project_id" WHERE     "projects_users"."user_id" = ? ORDER BY "projects"."created_at" DESC LIMIT     ?  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Project id: 1, name: "Project 1", description: "Description", course_id: 1, created_at: "2019-06-28 17:33:46", updated_at: "2019-06-28 17:33:46">, #<Project id: 1, name: "Project 1", description: "Description", course_id: 1, created_at: " 2019-06-28 17:33:46", updated_at: "2019-06-28 17:33:46">]>
irb(main):002:0>
```

Users and Projects Join Migration:

```
def change
  create_join_table :projects, :users do |t|
    t.index [:project_id, :user_id]
  end
end
```

Edit:

I have a weird issue. I tried this on safari and it worked perfectly but when try it on chrome, User.first.projects still returns 2 of the same projects.

Comment: Can you show you console logs?

Comment: @MaxVinícius Ive added it in the edit

Comment: how is your `projects` relationship defined in your User model ?

Comment: @fanta Projects and users have a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Comment: got it, could it be possible that you accepted the submission twice ?. open your rails console and update `accepted` to `false`, and delete the records that associate the `projects` with your `submission`, and then accept it again

Comment: @fanta. I tried that. It always returns 2 projects

Comment: Just for test. Add `validates :project_id, uniqueness: true` to your model.

Comment: @MaxVinícius Ok I added that to my submission model and created a new project and a new submission after migrating the database. User.first.projects still returns each project twice

Comment: @fanta I tried my code on safari and it worked. It just doesn't work on chrome.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense, is it then that chrome is sending the request twice ?, that seems to be a js issue ?